# Scrape data from a link within a webpage. python, beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the insta profile, put in the url (@priyankachopra) in a table on the website, https://starngage.com/app/global/influencer/ranking/india

The data i am trying to scrape is:
username, age, bio, follower count, following count, engagement rate, avg likes, avg comments, total posts, profile pic url, profile picture

similarly i want to print same data from first 1000 insta profiles and put them in a excel file.

I am only able to scrape follower count follower count, following count, engagement rate, avg likes, avg comments, total posts

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://starngage.com/app/global/influencer/ranking/india').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)


celebs = [[each_celeb.find_all('td')[2].text.strip(), 
          each_celeb.find_all('td')[2].find('a').text,
          each_celeb.find_all('td')[2].find('a')['href']] 
          for each_celeb in soup.find('table', class_ = 'table table-hover table-responsive-sm').find('tbody').find_all('tr')]

required = {}

for each_celeb in celebs[:10]:
    r = requests.get(each_celeb[2]).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
    data = [[each_data.find('h6').text.strip(),
        each_data.find_all('div')[-1].text] for each_data in soup.find('div', class_='row row-cards summary').find_all('div', class_='card-body p-3')]
    required[each_celeb[0]] = data
    
print(required)
```

Comment: Why your question looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68421512/scrape-data-from-a-link-in-a-webpage-using-beautiful-soup-python)? Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that code. I do not know what do you mean under profile picture - so I download image and convert it to base64.

```
import requests
import base64
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# main page
all_actors = []
r = requests.get(
    'https://starngage.com/app/global/influencer/ranking/india'
).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

# loop via all accounts
humans_table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table-hover'})
table_rows = humans_table.find_all('tr')

for row in table_rows:
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    if columns:
        # link to full page
        full_page = columns[2].find('a')['href']

        # send request
        profile = requests.get(full_page).text
        profile_soup = BeautifulSoup(profile, 'html.parser')

        # get extra data
        card_body = profile_soup.find('div', {'class': 'card-body'})
        flex_columns = card_body.find_all('div', {'class': 'd-flex'})

        # get profile picture
        profile_picture = requests.get(columns[1].find('img')['src'])

        profile_picture_b64 = ("data:" +
                               profile_picture.headers['Content-Type'] + ";" +
                               "base64," +
                               base64.b64encode(
                                   profile_picture.content
                               ).decode('utf-8'))

        # create actor

        # sometimes we do not have age
        try:
            age = flex_columns[2].text
        except IndexError:
            age = ''

        actor = {
            'username': columns[2].find('a').text,
            'age': age,
            'bio': card_body.find('div', {'class': 'text-secondary'}).text,
            'following_count': columns[5].text,
            'engagement_rate': columns[6].text,
            'avg_likes': profile_soup.find('div', {
                'class': 'avg-likes'
            }).find('div', {
                'class': 'text-number'
            }).text,
            'avg_comments': profile_soup.find('div', {
                'class': 'avg-comments'
            }).find('div', {
                'class': 'text-number'
            }).text,
            'total_posts': profile_soup.find('div', {
                'class': 'posts'
            }).find('div', {
                'class': 'text-number'
            }).text,
            'profile_pic_url': columns[1].find('img')['src'],
            'profile_picture': profile_picture_b64
        }

        # append to actors list
        all_actors.append(actor)

# write data to csv file
fieldnames = [
    'username', 'age', 'bio', 'following_count', 'engagement_rate',
    'avg_likes', 'avg_comments', 'total_posts', 'profile_pic_url',
    'profile_picture'
]
with open('result.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(all_actors)
```

Comment: age': flex_columns[2].text,
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @jamesfox you got it on first iteration?

Comment: @jamesfox yeah i see, in some cases there are no age data. change answer

Comment: how to print the csv data,
also how to generate the csv file

Comment: My code have answer on your question. In the end we create file and write data there

Comment: not printing anything

Comment: It create cvs file with data. Your question is how to write csv and parse data. So my answer is correct?